# Decrement or increment a variable in the robot framework

Tags: variables, robotframework

I just want to decrement the variable N_groups in the last line.
This is my robot file:

```
Preconditions - Delete Groups But Not First
    ${N_groups}    Setup Groups Count Groups
    Log to console    N_groups: ${N_groups}
    : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    20
    \    Run Keyword If    '${N_groups}' == '1'    Exit For Loop
    \    Setup Groups Delete Group    ${group}
    \    ${N_groups}=    ${N_groups}-1
```

I get the error:

`No keyword with name '${N_groups}-1' found.`

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting it inside the var name. i.e.

```
${N_groups-1}
```

Comment: this is not intuitive

Comment: yeah I remember hitting exactly the same stumbling block months ago, coming from development it just feels wrong, like I'm using a completely different variable rather than changing a variable's value.  But I guess syntax is syntax

Comment: @kame: it's not intuitive, but it's a documented feature: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax

Answer (score 5):

If the variable is already a number, you can use:

`${N_groups}=    ${N_groups-1}`

To do this you need to coerce it to a number (otherwise you'll get an error saying `failed: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`), e.g.

`*** Variables ***
${N_groups}=    ${0}  # ${} notation coerces value to a number`

Alternatively, you can use `Evaluate` like this, which works whether ${N_groups} has been coerced to a number or not:

`${N_groups}=    Evaluate    ${N_groups} - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
${decrement_counter}=  set variable   1
```

-- inside the loop

```
${N_groups}=   Evaluate    ${N_groups} - ${decrement_counter}
```

Note - only one space before and after subtraction sign.